# How do i get rid of heap corruption detected. Class Vector

Tags: c++, vector, heap-corruption

i am trying to make my own Vector and after i changed the move constructor i get Heap corruption detected: after normal block (#34115).

This is the move constructor:

```
template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(Vector&& other)
    : m_nrOfElements(std::exchange(other.m_nrOfElements, 0)), 
      m_capacity(std::exchange(other.m_capacity, 0)), 
      m_elements(std::exchange(other.m_elements, nullptr))
{
    
}
```

This is the code in its total:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    int m_capacity;
    int m_nrOfElements;
    T* m_elements;

public:
    Vector();

    Vector(const Vector& other);
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& other);

    Vector(Vector&& other);
    Vector& operator=(Vector&& other);

    Vector(int index, T element);

    ~Vector();

    T& operator[](const int index) const;
    T& at(const int index) const;
    T& front() const;
    T& back() const;

    const T* data() const;

    void push_back(const T& element);
    void pop_back();

    bool empty() const;
    int size()const;
    int capacity() const;

    void insert(int index, const T& element);
    void erase(int index);
    void clear();

};

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector()
    :m_nrOfElements(0),
     m_capacity(5),
     m_elements(new T[m_capacity])
{

}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector& other)
    :m_nrOfElements(other.m_nrOfElements),
     m_capacity(other.m_capacity),
     m_elements(new T[m_capacity])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.m_nrOfElements; ++i)
    {
        m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i];
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(int index, T element)
    :m_nrOfElements(index),
     m_capacity(index +5),
     m_elements(new T[m_capacity])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nrOfElements; ++i)
    {
        m_elements[i] = element;
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& other)
{
    if (other.m_nrOfElements > m_nrOfElements)
    {
        delete[] m_elements;
        m_capacity = other.m_capacity;
        m_elements = new T[other.m_nrOfElements];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < other.m_nrOfElements; i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i];
    }
    m_nrOfElements = other.m_nrOfElements;

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(Vector&& other)
    : m_nrOfElements(std::exchange(other.m_nrOfElements, 0)), 
      m_capacity(std::exchange(other.m_capacity, 0)), 
      m_elements(std::exchange(other.m_elements, nullptr))
{
    
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(Vector&& other)
{
    delete[] m_elements;
    m_nrOfElements = other.m_nrOfElements;
    m_capacity = other.m_capacity;

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size(); i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i];
    }
    other.m_elements = nullptr;
    other.m_capacity = 0;
    other.m_nrOfElements = 0;

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] m_elements;
}

template<typename T>
inline T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int index) const
{
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= m_nrOfElements))
    {
        throw std::exception("Index out of range");
    }
    return m_elements[index];
}

template<typename T>
inline T& Vector<T>::at(const int index) const
{
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= m_nrOfElements))
    {
        throw std::exception("Index out of range");
    }
    return m_elements[index];
}

template<typename T>
inline T& Vector<T>::front() const
{   
    if (m_nrOfElements == 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return m_elements[0];
}

template<typename T>
inline T& Vector<T>::back() const
{
    if (m_nrOfElements == 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return m_elements[m_nrOfElements - 1];
}

template<typename T>
inline const T* Vector<T>::data() const
{
    return m_elements;
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& element)
{
    if (m_nrOfElements < m_capacity)
    {
        m_elements[m_nrOfElements] = element;
        m_nrOfElements++;
    }
    else
    {
        m_capacity *= 2;
        T* newArray = new T[m_capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_nrOfElements; ++i)
        {
            newArray[i] = m_elements[i];
        }
        newArray[m_nrOfElements] = element;
        ++m_nrOfElements;
        delete[] m_elements;
        m_elements = newArray;
        push_back(element);
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::pop_back()
{
    if (m_nrOfElements == 0)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        --m_nrOfElements;
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline bool Vector<T>::empty() const
{
    return m_nrOfElements == 0;
}

template<typename T>
inline int Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return m_nrOfElements;
}

template<typename T>
inline int Vector<T>::capacity() const
{
    return m_capacity;
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::insert(int index, const T& element)
{

    if ((index < 0) || (index >= m_nrOfElements))
    {
        throw std::exception("Insert index out of range");
    }
    if (m_nrOfElements != m_capacity)
    {
        for (int i = m_nrOfElements - 1; i >= index; --i)
        {
            m_elements[i + 1] = m_elements[i];
        }
        m_elements[index] = element;
        ++m_nrOfElements;
    }
    else
    {
        m_capacity *= 2;
        T* newArray = new T[m_capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_nrOfElements; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = m_elements[i];
        }
        delete[] m_elements;
        m_elements = newArray;
        insert(index, element);
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::erase(int index)
{
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= m_nrOfElements))
    {
        throw std::exception("Erase index out of range");
    }
    for (int i = index; i < m_nrOfElements - 1; i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = m_elements[i + 1];
    }
    --m_nrOfElements;
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::clear()
{
    m_nrOfElements = 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are compiling with "gcc" or "clang", you may want to compile with the `-fsanitize=address` command-line option. That way, you will probably immediately get an error message when the heap corruption occurs. Then, all you have to do is step through your code with a debugger, in order to determine exactly why it is happening.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. `other.m_nrOfElements > m_nrOfElements` should presumably be `other.m_nrOfElements > m_capacity`. Your move assignment operator deletes `m_elements` then copies to its elements, I guess this is what's crashing not your move constructor?

Comment: Your move assign operator is wrong, you are actually copying elements in to the deleted old array instead of just moving the pointer.

Comment: Just a side note, this template will not work for any non-default-constructible and/or non-copyable element type.

Answer (score 1):

As @jo-art commented, your move constructor seems OK; however, the move assignment operator is:

1. Deallocating `m_elements`.
2. Copying from `other.m_elements` to a destination pointer you've just deleted (invalid access).
3. Setting `other.m_elements` to nullptr without deallocating it first (memory leak).

```cpp
    delete[] m_elements;
    m_nrOfElements = other.m_nrOfElements;
    m_capacity = other.m_capacity;

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size(); i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i];
    }

    other.m_elements = nullptr;
    other.m_capacity = 0;
    other.m_nrOfElements = 0;
```

Instead:

1. Deallocate `m_elements`.
2. Move the data from `other` as you do at the move constructor.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/nWPcv814x)

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(Vector&& other)
    : m_nrOfElements(std::exchange(other.m_nrOfElements, 0)), 
      m_capacity(std::exchange(other.m_capacity, 0)), 
      m_elements(std::exchange(other.m_elements, nullptr))
{   
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(Vector&& other)
{
    delete[] m_elements;
    
    m_nrOfElements = std::exchange(other.m_nrOfElements, 0);
    m_capacity = std::exchange(other.m_capacity, 0);
    m_elements = std::exchange(other.m_elements, nullptr);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This probably makes it better. But its still the same error :(

Comment: Can you post the code that is firing the heap corruption? Could you please add it to my [online demo example](https://godbolt.org/z/nWPcv814x)?